# AttributeError: __exit__ error on custom operator

Tags: python, scripting

I'm new to both python and scripting in Blender, so I am sure this is just my misunderstanding of how python and the Blender API work. I have no idea what this error means.

This is the full traceback for my error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/clipImporter.py", line 103, in execute
  File "/clipImporter.py", line 78, in scan_files
AttributeError: __exit__

location: <unknown location>:-1

location: <unknown location>:-1
```

So as the file name suggests, I am just making an importer to bring in clips, objects from libraries or whatever. I have a similar script working for .blend objects, but trying to do it with movie clips is giving me this error. So I have a suspicion that it is my misuse of datablocks. Here's some more relevant code:

**The Function**

```
def scan_files(folderpath, datablock):
    exec("bpy.context.scene." + datablock + "_directory_list.clear()")  
    exec("bpy.context.scene." + datablock + "_directory_index = 0")  

    folderpath = bpy.path.abspath(folderpath)

    for file in os.listdir(folderpath):
        filepath = folderpath + "\\" + file
        with bpy.data.movieclips.load(filepath) as (data_from, data_to):  # this is line 78...I have a feeling it's movieclips.load
            for name in eval("data_from" + datablock):
                my_item = eval("bpy.context.scene" + datablock + "_directory_list.add()")
                my_item.name = name  # these two correspond to custom props group
                my_item.file = file
```

**The Class**

```
def execute(self, context):
        if bpy.context.scene.dir_clip:
            if context.scene.folderpath_clip:
                scan_files(context.scene.folderpath_clip, "clip")  #this is line 103

        return{'FINISHED'}
```

I've been hacking and slashing [this guy's script](http://vincentgires.com/tools/blender/addons/blend_library/v032/blend_library.py) to do what I want if you want to see his logic behind his importing. The scan files function is scanning a directory and loading available options to import.

If you need the whole script let me know and I'll do a pasteall, though I'm sure I could probably solve the error if I even knew what `AttributeError: __exit__` actually meant. I do come from a bit of a C# background, so an explanation paralleled to that would be fabulous.

Thanks lovely people!

Comment: see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24513070/attributeerror-exit-when-i-try-to-mock-out-build-in-functions) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7447284/how-to-troubleshoot-an-attributeerror-exit-in-multiproccesing-in-python)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

focus on the code around the error:

```
import bpy

files = ['/home/zeffii/GL_fillet.mpeg', '/home/zeffii/GL_fillet2.mpeg']

for filepath in files:
    with bpy.data.movieclips.load(filepath) as (data_from, data_to):
        print(data_from, data_to)
```

Even from that snippet I get `AttributeError: __exit__`

I may be wrong, but this suggests to me that there is no context manager (in the python sense, not in the bpy.context sense) to use `with x.y.z as (a, b)` on the `bpy.data.movieclips.load()` operator. Hence that error. The [documentation confirms](http://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_74_release/bpy.types.BlendDataMovieClips.html?highlight=movieclips.load#bpy.types.BlendDataMovieClips.load) this. `movieclips.load()` does return an object though!

If you just want to get stuff done, rewrite it so it doesn't use the `with x.y.z as (a,b)` context, instead assign to the left.

```
import bpy

files = ['/home/zeffii/GL_fillet.mpeg', '/home/zeffii/GL_fillet2.mpeg']

for filepath in files:
    clip = bpy.data.movieclips.load(filepath)
    # you know what you need here.
    print(clip.name)
    print(clip.size[:])
    print(clip.source)

>>> GL_fillet.mpeg
>>> (1280, 720)
>>> MOVIE
>>> GL_fillet2.mpeg
>>> (1280, 720)
>>> MOVIE
```

Additionally, there's also a typo I think. The original code has

```
for name in eval("data_from." + datablock):
    # blah..
```

and you omit a necessary `.` after `data_from.`.

Your `scan_files` function for movie_clips might start to look something like:

```
def scan_files(folderpath, datablock):
    exec("bpy.context.scene." + datablock + "_directory_list.clear()")  
    exec("bpy.context.scene." + datablock + "_directory_index = 0")  

    folderpath = bpy.path.abspath(folderpath)

    for _file in os.listdir(folderpath):
        filepath = folderpath + "\\" + file
        clip = bpy.data.movieclips.load(filepath)

        data_from = ...  # clip.name ?
        data_to = ... # clip.source ?

        for name in eval("data_from." + datablock):
            my_item = eval("bpy.context.scene" + datablock + "_directory_list.add()")
            my_item.name = name  # these two correspond to custom props group
            my_item.file = _file
```

Without seeing more of your code (got a github repository?) I'm not able to say more. Looks like an interesting project though.

Comment: Ah, thank you so much! You are absolutely right, don't know how I missed that in the documentation. You are a star, thank you for your very thorough answer. Makes total sense.

Comment: The less travelled paths of the documentation are often quite terse, it means you're one of the few people to try stuff with that section of the API.